# Find all ordered triples of non-negative integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $2^a + 2^b = c!$.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> Find all ordered triples of non-negative integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $2^a + 2^b = c!$.

---

Here from the equation we have that if $a \le b$, then we have $2^a(1+2^{b-a}) = c!$, which implies that $2^a$ divides $c!$.

Next, we know that $c! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 \times \cdots \times c$ and all the even terms contribute a factor of $2$.

If $a=b$, then we have $2^{a+1} = c!$ and this is only possible if $a=0 =b$ and $c = 2$. Thus $(0,0,2)$ is a solution.

I am stuck here. Any hints are welcome.

Comment: The highest power of $2$ dividing $n!$ is shown in [OEIS A011371](https://oeis.org/A011371)

Comment: Hint: For $c\ge5$, the RHS is divisible by 15. Try and work mod 15 on the LHS to reduce the values of c